# Delete a key from every element in a JSON Array - Ruby

Tags: arrays, json, ruby

So, I have a JSON array through which I am looping, and adding three keys and their values, I also want to remove/delete a key(subject_id) from every element in the array.

How to go about doing this?

```
s=JSON.parse(subjects.to_json)
s.each do |j|
  j["total_classes"] = total_classes[i]
  j["attended_classes"] = attended_classes[i]
  j["subject_name"] = subject_name[i]
  j["subject_id"] #remove this key, how?
  i=i+1
end

render json: { attendances: s }
```

Comment: The first thing you do is convert a JSON string to an array, each element of which is a hash. You want to know how to delete the same key from every hash. The fact that you got the hash from a JSON string is  irrelevant, and since you obviously must loop through each element of the array, the question really boils down to wanting to know how to delete a key from a hash. To answer that question you need only look through [Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html)'s instance methods for one that will do that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this one

```
j.delete("subject_id")
```

Comment: that worked. thanks. seems like I need to get a grip on my basics.

Comment: My pleasure Sir ;)